# When writing a single document to GCP Firestore, are you billed the same amount regardless of document size?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm deciding on a NoSQL database. I've noticed a surprising difference between AWS billing and GCP billing for their flagship NoSQL products.

[AWS DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/) charges $1.25/million "WRUs," or Write Request Units. 1 WRU is billed for storing a document up to 1 KB in size. If you write a document that is larger than 1 KB, DynamoDB bills additional WRUs.

[GCP Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) charges $1.8/million "Document Writes." No mention is made of document size limitations, outside the limits page, which says that each document can be up to 1 MiB in size.

So, if I'm thinking about this correctly, if I stored 1 million 4KiB documents in DynamoDB, it would cost me 4 million WRUs, which adds up to $5. If I did the same in Firestore, it would only cost me 1 million writes, which is $1.8.

If I write 1 million 400KiB documents to DynamoDB, it would cost 400 million WRUs, which adds up to $500. But this same operation in Firestore would still be 1 million writes, which is still only $1.8.

**I'm surprised by this.** This large disparity in price is, in my experience, not common for cloud compute platforms.

When writing to GCP Firestore, are you billed the same amount regardless of document size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore charges for:

0. Storage data
1. Document write operations
2. Document read operations
3. Bandwidth consumed by read operations, aka Network egress

There is (as you noticed) no charge for the size of document writes, which indeed leads to favorable results in the comparison you make with writing relatively large documents.

In my experience most write operations performed from client-side application code result in documents that are quite small (a few KB at most) though, so you'll want to validate your expected document size first and then compare again.